# Package newunicodechar Error: ASCII character requested

Tags: newunicodechar

I've tried using the newunicode, but I've fallen on this problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{Γ}{\ensuremath{\Gamma}}

\begin{document}

Γ

\end{document}
```

This should just replace all "Γ" into "\Gamma", which is supported by LateX.

But instead, I just get an "?" when compiling...

How can I change this?

Comment: check that your file is saved in utf-8

Comment: please show the exact error that you get, copied from the log file. (The above example runs without error if copied from the website and saved as UTF-8)

Comment: I only get the error if I save the file as ISO-8859-7 instead of UTF-8. The ISO encoding is not supported by `newunicodechar` and reading the file with the `utf8` option is meaningless anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file as posted in the question is in UTF-8, matching the encoding declared to LaTeX. If you save it as 8bit Greek (ISO-2022 for example) then you get

```
! Package newunicodechar Error: ASCII character requested.

See the newunicodechar package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.5 \newunicodechar{�}{\ensuremath{\Gamma}}
```

as the encoding is incorrectly declared. The solution is to ensure that your editor saves the file as UTF-8.

Comment: And how do I save the file as UTF-8?

Comment: @Taumen in most editors this century it will be the default, however if you say which editor you are using, someone can probably show you where to set that.

Comment: @Taumen note the example in your question as posted above is in UTF-8 (all the text on this site is) so if you copy that to a file on your system it will be in UTF-8 unless you (or your editor) actually re-encodes it to something else.